# How to get Response values (Login Responses) from retrofit android

Tags: android, retrofit2

i am beginner of Android Learner,i used retrofit in my project,i get responses from login Request

```
{"android":{"msg":"User login successfull","data":{"id":"14","name":"meena","url":"","email":"meena04@gmail.com","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","phone":"","country":"China","photo":"","status":"pending","role":"3","device_id":"","oauth_uid":"","resume":"","oauth_provider":null,"created":"1503316508"}}}
```

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: LoginResponse getResult = response.body();
   Log.i("getResult",""+getResult); i can't print the response values,where i going to get

Comment: Parse Parse Parse!!! Parse it

Answer (score 2):

try this to you can parse your json like this

```
try
{

  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
  String msg= data.getString("msg")// get your msg

  JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");// now get your secong json object like this

   String id= data.getString("id");// get the id from data json object like this

   String name= data.getString("name");// get the name from data json object like this

   String url= data.getString("url");// get the url from data json object like this

   String email= data.getString("email");// get the email from data json object like this

   String password= data.getString("password");// get the password from data json object like this

   String phone= data.getString("phone") ; // get the phone from data json object like this

   String country= data.getString("country");// get the country from data json object like this

   String photo= data.getString("photo");// get the photo from data json object like this

   String status= data.getString("status");// get the status from data json object like this

   String role= data.getString("role");// get the role from data json object like this

   String device_id= data.getString("device_id");// get the device_id from data json object like this

   String oauth_uid= data.getString("oauth_uid");// get the oauth_id from data json object like this

   String resume= data.getString("resume");// get the resune from data json object like this

   String oauth_provider= data.getString("oauth_provider");// get the oauth_provider from data json object like this

   String created= data.getString("created");// get the created from data json object like this

    Log.e("RESULT :-> ",msg+" "+id+""+name+"  "+url+""+email+""+password+" "+phone+" "+phone
    +country+" "+photo+""+status+" "+role+" "+device_id+" "+resume+"  "+oauth_provider+" "+created+ " ");

 } catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: how to get that "JsonResponseString" ,if i use to print the values,using  
LoginResponse getResult = response.body(); Log.i("getResult",""+getResult); getResult: com.app.eduxhub.Model.LoginResponse@556defb

Comment: it is the respone you are getting from  from retrofit api

Comment: wait i ll check with your help code and update to you

Comment: my problem is i can't print the response in log ,{"android":{"msg":"User login successfull","data":{"id":"14","name":"meena","url":"","email":"meena04@gmail.com","password":"202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70","phone":"","country":"China","photo":"","status":"pending","role":"3","device_id":"","oauth_uid":"","resume":"","oauth_provider":null,"created":"1503316508"}}}

Comment: with the above code you can print that response  @SelvaMeena

Comment: i am getting error i can't getresults,  W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value com.app.Model.LoginResponse@9c7472e of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: get result menans it responese from your retrofit @SelvaMeena

Comment: @SelvaMeena You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote and mark the answers as accepted so it's clear to others that your question doesn't need more answers.

Comment: If you use retrofit this is a totally wrong way to go

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson for this :

first, create a pojo using http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

let's name it Response class

now use gson as follows:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Response Response = gson.
                                fromJson(response.toString(), Response.class);
```

best method :
1. use retrofit Gson library compile

```
'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```

2. add GsonFactory to retrofit

   new Retrofit.Builder()
                   .baseUrl(Common.Urls.BaseURL)
                   .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
3. create pojo as above
4. observe retrofit response as a class object:

   @POST(Common.Urls.LOGIN_API)
           Observable signIn(@Body HashMap request);